# How to compare fetched ObjectID with string?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, comparison, string-comparison

I have a view controller that shows details of an item in Core Data.  The specific item to look up is passed to the controller from the previous controller.

Here is the basic code:

```
class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!

var selectedItemObjectID:String!

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

                //Fetch the the list of items from the context
                var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
                var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
                var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
                var error: NSError?
                var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

                //optional, avoids potential compiler error
                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                if (results.count > 0) {
                    for fetchResult in results {
                        println("POPULATING THE DETAILS PAGE...")
                        println("fetchResult.objectID is \(fetchResult.objectID)")
                        println("selectedItemObjectID is \(selectedItemObjectID)")
                        //If the array entry matches the data passed to us, then populate the item details screen
                        if (fetchResult.objectID  == selectedItemObjectID) { 
                            itemLabel.text = fetchResult.valueForKey("itemName") as? String         
                } else {
                    println("No items in the database...")
                }
            }
```

The problem I am having is that, to my eyes, both of the objectID's I compare to each other look exactly the same.  Yet the if statement is not triggered and itemLabel.text is never changed.  Here is the output when the for loop iterates through the one that should be a match:

```
POPULATING THE DETAILS PAGE...
fetchResult.objectID is 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://5F0AE77F-A83A-41BC-9361-0DE37F120776/Item/p2>
selectedItemObjectID is 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://5F0AE77F-A83A-41BC-9361-0DE37F120776/Item/p2>
```

They look exactly the same!  Is my if statement formed wrong?  Am I going about using objectID's the wrong way?

Comment: Your code does not match the output ("selectedItemObjectID" vs "selectedAquariumObjectID"). –  Did you post your *real* code?

Comment: Your code is hard to follow. You declared `var selectedItemmObjectID` (note the double m), but later on you use it with single m (`fetchResult.objectID  == selectedItemObjectID`). Also, the `fetchResult.objectID  == selectedItemObjectID` should not compile, because you are comparing `NSManagedObjectId` with `String`. The sample output does not match the code (and variable types). Could you provide more up to date code?

Comment: Thanks, I edited it.  This is an abridged version of my code.  I cut out all the BS and tried to leave the important parts.  It does compile.  The biggest question I have is how do I test if the string matches the objectID.  Because my if statement doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  In the if comparison, I needed to use fetchresult.fetchResult.objectID.description instead of fetchresult.fetchResult.objectID.

See the corrected code below:

```
class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!

var selectedItemObjectID:String!

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

                //Fetch the the list of items from the context
                var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
                var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
                var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
                var error: NSError?
                var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)!

                //optional, avoids potential compiler error
                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

                if (results.count > 0) {
                    for fetchResult in results {
                        println("POPULATING THE DETAILS PAGE...")
                        println("fetchResult.objectID is \(fetchResult.objectID)")
                        println("selectedItemObjectID is \(selectedItemObjectID)")
                        //If the array entry matches the data passed to us, then populate the item details screen
                        if (fetchResult.objectID.description  == selectedItemObjectID) { 
                            itemLabel.text = fetchResult.valueForKey("itemName") as? String         
                } else {
                    println("No items in the database...")
                }
            }
```